# Map values to any multidimensional array

Tags: code-golf, array, integer

### Codegolf challenge - mapping values in a multidimensional array

```js
[
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]
]
```

This **2D** array is sick of being so **false**, and wants to find the **truth** about life, once and **for** all. Your task is to write a map function to act as a highway to all the values in this array.

An example implementation of this super function would be if the above array is defined as `arr` below:

```js
arr.multimap(x => {
  return 1;
}
```

Which would result in the array being:

```
[
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]
]
```

This is a 2D number example, yours has to work in any dimension, and not be dimensionally-bias.

---

### The rules

- Must work in any type of dimensional array (1D, 2D, 3D, etc..)
- Least bytes, wins!
- Must only have one callback function which accounts for any level of dimensional interaction
- Meta-languages get fewer points
- Can simply be a function which applies the logic to an array given
- Can be any arbitrary initial value, as long as you can replace it on-command

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. This conversation has [been moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92808/discussion-on-question-by-jack-hales-map-values-to-any-multidimensional-array).

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>35</s> <s>27</s> 17 bytes

*-18 thanks to @Arnauld and @Shaggy*

```js
f=a=>a?a.map(f):1

console.log(f([
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, [0, 0, 0], 0],
  [[0, 0, [0]], 0, 0]
]))
```

Comment: @Arnauld lol, you are right. Thanks!

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1i5RLzexwB5MaqRpWhn@T87PK87PSdXLyU/X8Ar299MrLinKzEvPTKvUSNOI5lJQiDbQUQChWB0oByEAE4SKRBvExkKluGI1NTX/AwA)

Comment: @Arnauld: Or [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1i7RPlEvN7FAI03TyvB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrqGV7C/n15xSVFmXnpmWqVGmkZ0tIEOEMbqAGkYE8QDs6MNYmPBQrGampr/AQ)

Comment: @Shaggy Yup, but it's still unclear if the initial values are guaranteed to be falsy (see the last rule).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4z///9HcykoRBvoKIBQrA6UgxCACUJFog1iY6FSXLEA)

Replaces `n` with `n + 1`.

Because Jelly things.

Note that `[x]` displays as `x` in Jelly (single-element lists don't show as lists); the internal data is still a single-element list. You can make it show using Python's `str`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yjkx7unPH///9oLgWFaAMdBRCK1YFyEAIwQahItEFsLFSKKxYA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>29</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan*

*-1 byte thanks to @JoKing*

```python
f=lambda a:a<1or map(f,a)
```

Replaces `0` with `True`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIdEq0cYwv0ghN7FAI00nUfN/QVFmXolCUWpBkUaaRjSXgkK0gY4CCMXqQDkIAZggVCTaIDYWIgVkRwOZ0bGxsVyxmpr/AQ)

Comment: [Python 2, 26](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIdEq0SY6Nr9IITexQCNNJ1Hzf0FRZl6JQlFqQZFGmkY0l4JCtIGOAgjF6kA5CAGYIFQk2iA2FiIFZEcDmdGxsbFcsZqa/wE)

Comment: @Neil the `f=` is necessary for a recursive function.

Comment: `<[]` can be `<1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 4 bytes

```perl6
!<<*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf0cZG6781F1dxYqVCmkZ0tIEOEMYCCSAzFkiASCCMjdW0hqkByoGlwDIgFToQJZrW/wE)

Replaces `0`s with `True`. *Extremely* short for a non-esolang.

```perl6
   *  # From the input
!     # Boolean not 
 <<   # Each element recursively
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
?¡ßX:1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=P6HfWDox&input=W1swLDAsMF0sWzAsWzAsMCwwXSwwXSxbWzAsMCxbMF1dLDAsMF1dCi1R)

```
¬Íª¡ßX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rM2qod9Y&input=W1swLDAsMF0sWzAsWzAsMCwwXSwwXSxbWzAsMCxbMF1dLDAsMF1dCi1R)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 36 bytes

```javascript
t=>JSON.stringify(t).replace(/0/g,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/E1s4r2N9Pr7ikKDMvPTOtUqNEU68otSAnMTlVQ99AP13HUPN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmkY0l4JCtIGOAgjF6kA5CAGYIFQk2iA2FirFFaup@R8A)